# Is publishProgress method of AsyncTask asynchronous?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've used `AsyncTask` quite a bit - but I have come across a seemingly simple question that confused me. The question is this:

> Is `publishProgress(Progress... values)` supposed to return
>   immediately? In other words, is this method asynchronous?

## Some Context:

I'm trying to determine whether the following code

- Fires an HTTP request every three seconds, regardless of the response ***OR***
- Fires an HTTP request, waits for the response, and ***then*** sleeps for three seconds before firing the next request.

public class MyAsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground(String... params) {
    while (mRunning) {
        // Call publishProgress
        this.publishProgress(makeHttpRequest());

        // Sleep for 3 seconds
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lock.wait(3 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private HttpResponse makeHttpRequest() {
    HttpResponse ajaxResponse = null;
    Throwable throwable = null;
    try {
        ajaxResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Handle exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exception
    }

    return ajaxResponse;

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(HttpResponse... values) {
    // Do something with the response
}
```

}

Comment: reading the documentation doesnt hurt .... `publishProgress ... This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.`

Comment: What I understood from reading this was that `doInBackground()` continues to execute even while progress is being published. I couldn't conclude anything from that though. I might be wrong - which is why I asked this question here at SO.

Comment: still, sending HttpResponse to onProgressUpdate(Progress...) have no sense, since you will do response processing on UI thread and this can provide to ANR ... you should separate UI code from processing code

Comment: This was a simplified code to demonstrate my issue. My actual code does the response processing in `makeHttpRequest` and passes a custom `RestResponse` object to `publishProgress()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.publishProgress(makeHttpRequest());
```

is equals to (Java can't pass methods. Just the results)

```
HttpResponse resp = makeHttpRequest();
this.publishProgess(resp);
```

so `makeHttpReqest` is done in the background.

You than pass the `HttpResponse` Object to `publishProgress` which returns immediately. The progress Object is then asynchronously send to `onProgressUpdate()` in the UI thread.

-> it's the *then sleeps* way.

Comment: Ah - that explains it. What was I thinking!

Answer (score 4):

You're asking two different things here:

- `publishProgress()` does indeed return instantly, it just posts a message to some `Handler`
- Unrelated to how `publishProgress()` behaves, your code would always execute the HTTP request, wait for the response, then sleep three seconds. Just inlining method calls like `publishProgress(makeHttpRequest())` doesn't mean that  `makeHttpRequest()` isn't executed right where it's called, in your `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: Great explanation! @zapl beat you to it by 45 seconds though :)